# maya python check is user has faces or objects selected

Tags: python, maya

I want to do a simple test and confirm if the user has faces, verts or object selected. And return the number 0 for faces, 1 for verts and 3 if objects are selected.

This snippet of code appears to not provide information that i could easily test

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
selection = cmds.ls(sl=True)[0]
print type(selection)
print selection
```

What i'am simply trying to achieve :

```
if selection == 0:
    do...
elif selection == 1
    do...
elif selection == 2:
    do...
```

Answer (score 1):

[`cmds.polyListComponentConversion`](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/search-result/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2016/ENU/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/polyListComponentConversion-html.html) works as filter on component selections.  If you 'convert' from a type to itself, you filter it.  Add in `type = float3` on an ls command to ignore whole objects and you get something like this :

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
from collections import namedtuple
selectiontype = namedtuple('selectiontype', 'faces verts edges')

def get_selected_components():
    sel = cmds.ls(sl=True, type = 'float3') # this is obscure maya way to get only components
    faces = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(sel, ff=True, tf =True)
    verts = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(sel, fv=True, tv =True)
    edges = cmds.polyListComponentConversion(sel, fe=True, te =True)
    return selectiontype (faces, verts, edges)


get_selected_components()
# Result: selectiontype(faces=[], verts=[u'pSphere1.vtx[0:381]', u'pTorus1.vtx[112]', u'pTorus1.vtx[131:132]', u'pTorus1.vtx[151:154]', u'pTorus1.vtx[171:174]', u'pTorus1.vtx[191:194]', u'pTorus1.vtx[211:214]', u'pTorus1.vtx[231:234]', u'pTorus1.vtx[251:254]', u'pTorus1.vtx[272:274]'], edges=[]) #
```

Instead of numbers in the code that uses this, just use a vanilla python if-check:

```
selected = get_selected_components()
if selected.faces:
     # do something

if selected.verts:
     # something else
```

you probably don't want to do `if 1:.... if 2:....` because it is possible for the selection to contain a mix of things; it's not that hard for the user to have some of all three types selected at once

Answer (score 0):

```
if '.f[' in selection:
    do...
elif '.e[' in selection
    do...
elif '.vtx[' in selection:
    do...
elif '.' not in selection:
    do...
```